# Angular JS Directive with ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I have a pagination links directive,

```
app.directive('postsPagination', function(){  
return{
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<ul class="pagination" ng-show="totalPages > 1">'+
    '<li ng-class="disabled: currentPage!=1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getPosts(1)">&laquo;</a></li>'+
    '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getPosts(currentPage-1)">&lsaquo; Prev</a></li>'+
    '<li ng-repeat="i in range" ng-class="{active : currentPage == i}">'+
        '<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getPosts(i)">{{i}}</a>'+
    '</li>'+
    '<li ng-show="currentPage != totalPages"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getPosts(currentPage+1)">Next &rsaquo;</a></li>'+
    '<li ng-show="currentPage != totalPages"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getPosts(totalPages)">&raquo;</a></li>'+
  '</ul>'
};
});
```

The ng-class is not working when the value of current page is not equel to 1.

```
<li ng-class="disabled: currentPage!=1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getPosts(1)">&laquo;</a></li>'+
```

This is the error.

[image]

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: is the name of your class is disabled ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: if currentPage !=1, I want to add class named "disabled"

Comment: try wrapping the code in `{}` like `ng-class="{disabled: currentPage!=1}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the code in `{}` like:

```
ng-class="{disabled: currentPage!=1}"
```